# $f(x)=2-|x-3|, 1\le x\le 5$ and for other values, $f(x)$ is obtained using the relation $f(5x)=kf(x)$ for $x\in R$. then...

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, continuity

Question: The maximum value of f(x) in $[5^4,5^5]$ for $k=2$ is? Also, if $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_1^xf(x)dx$$ is a finite number, find the exhaustive set of $k$.

**Attempt :**

For first part, $f(5x)=2f(x)$. Now I need to find the nature of the function. Since $5x>x$ (the values $[5^4,5^5]$ are positive), and if $f(x)$ is a positive function, $f(5x)>f(x)$ which means the function is increasing. So maximum value is $f(5^5)=2f(5^4)=4f(5^3)=...=16f(5)=0$ since, at $x=5,y=0$. But the answer given is 32.

For second part, the integral can be split as $\int_1^5f(x)dx+\int_5^xf(x)dx = \int_1^3(1+x)dx+\int_3^5(5-x)dx+I=8+I$.
In both cases, I have to find $f(x)$ and its nature to proceed further. How do I find $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT....consider the graph of $f(x)$ which is an isosceles triangle with base from $x=1$ to $x=5$ and height $2$

Comment: What about $f(5x)=kf(x)$ part?

Comment: So you get more triangles. ... Try putting $x=1, x=3, x=5$ into this relationship

Comment: I will try again using the hint.

Comment: In the graph, I got triangles of increasing altitude but with same base. Hence maximum occures at $3\cdot 5^4$. Also, the altitudes increase $k$ times in triangle. So the answer is $2k^4=32$.

Comment: Ok, then, you can do the last pert?

Comment: I will. But for example, how will I calculate $f(2007)$?

Comment: $f(2007)=kf(\frac{2007}{5})=...?$. Continue until you have something you can evaluate from the original formula